# How to Delete A Specific File From AWS S3Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, ckeditor5

I am integrating CKEDITOR in react project and I am using AWS S3 bucket to upload the image that i add in text-editor.. Upload is working fine... The problem is if I delete the image in text-editor.It does not delete it from the AWS bucket.

Causing a lot of unwanted images in bucket. Hence , I need to delete the image from AWS server if it's not present in the text-editor..
How Can I do it??

I have the link to the image in the React Part as the repsonse of the upload.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a bucket name and key of that file in order to delete that file form AWS s3

```
const deleteS3Object = async (key, BUCKET_NAME) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
                accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
                secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            });
            var params = { Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: key };
            s3bucket.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                // an error occurred
                else resolve(data); // successful response
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```